# my share hosting has disabled all socket functions

Tags: security, curl, socket

I have hosted my website with [squarebrothers.com](http://squarebrothers.com/)

They have disabled curl_exec, fsockopen, socket_create functions.

They say that these are security vulnerabilities and they have blocked.

And they suggest that they can allow access to a single user but i have to bear the responsibility if there is a security breach.

why would a hosting company disable the very important functions ?

What could be the problem with socket_create ?

I could not do any webservice request from facebook, paypal, other payment gateway and so many other webservices.

Besides,

If they are enabling those functions for me then what are all the security measures i have to take?

Comment: The best security measure you can take is to go and find yourself a different host who has a better grasp of what security measures *they* can take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, they're restricting those functions because hackers can include remote websites which can, and will steal sensitive information from you and your website visitors without you even knowing it.

If security isn't of any concern to you, then find a new host. But if you value the security of your own emails, your bank account and your clients then rather use something like CURL or even sCURL instead to create the same remove connections.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave them and find another provider. Btw, they are restricting those functions for security considerations... like, they don't wanna see anyone running services (like irc bots) on given ports. Restricting fsockopen or socket_create can be understood, but it's their job to monitor what kind of socket activity the user creates. It's 1x1 in hosting. Restricting curl_exec is ridicolous.